Transforming the functions $a_t(y)$ and $b_t(x)$ through integration, in the Riemannian metric $g_t=a_t(y)dx^2+b_t(x)dy^2$
Consider the $1$-parameter family $(M_t,g_t)$ for $g_t=a_t(y)dx^2+b_t(x)dy^2$ with real $t>0$. Let $x,y>0$ so $M_t=\big\lbrace\Bbb R_t^2:x,y,t>0\big\rbrace$.
Say we form
$$ g_t^*=a_t(y)^*dx^2+b_t(x)^*dy^2 $$
where $$ A_t(s)=a_t(y)^*=\int_{0}^\infty y^s~a_t(y)~\frac{dy}{y} $$
and $$B_t(r)= b_t(x)^*=\int_{0}^\infty x^{r}~b_t(x)~\frac{dx}{x} $$
Now is there a relationship between the geometries defined by
$$g_t$$
and
$$G_t =A_t(s)drd\bar r+B_t(r)dsd\bar s $$
Specifically, we have that $r,s\in \Bbb C$ and it's assumed that $A_t(s)$ and $B_t(r)$ converge on some vertical strips.

To me $G_t$ is a twisted Kähler metric for warping functions $A_t(s),B_t(r)$. What spaces can $(N_t,G_t)$ be embedded in? Are $g_t$ and $G_t$ actually related? Can this relationship be made precise? The former is a real metric and the latter is a complex metric.

Any insights or feedback welcome!

This question feels a bit vague. You might need to define $M_t$, and definitely to get a good answer you’ll want to elaborate on what you want when you say “what does $G_t$ look like?” You probably had some other problems or thoughts in mind when you wondered about $G_t$, it would be good to share them

@FShrike okay, working on that currently

What is the underlying manifold? Is $M_t$ just $\mathbb{R}^2$ with different metrics on it?

@quarague $\Bbb R^2$ with $x,y,t>0$.

@quarague yes with different metrics on it
